# Limit of Random Walk dependant on number of Steps taken

Tags: random-variables, random-walk, characteristic-functions

Define $X_n$ to be position of a particle after $n$ seconds such after every second, particle moves up two $2$ with probability $1/2n$, it moves down $2$ units with probability $1/2n$ or it stays with probability $1-1/n$. What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$?

Using Characteristic functions, I was able to show that CF of the limit would be $\exp(-2\sin^2x) = \exp(\cos(2x)-1)$ but can anything be said about the distribution/density of the limit

Edit:
Define $Z_n$ st $P[Z_n=2]=P[Z_n=-2]=1/2n, P[Z_n=0]=1-1/n$
Then CF of $Z_n ={n-1\over n}+\cos2x/n=1-{1-\cos2x\over n}$
Since $X_n$ is sum of $n$ iid $Z_n$'s, $\phi_{X_n}=(1-{1-\cos2x\over n})^n$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{X_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-{1-\cos2x\over n}\right)^n=e^{\cos2x-1}=e^{-2\sin^2x}$$

Edit 2: $$P[X_n=0]=\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}{n\choose p,p,n-2p}{1\over 2n}^{2p}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-2p}$$
Can we find this limit? If as $n\to\infty$ this is 1, then my calculations would be wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you arrived at the given characteristic function?

Comment: @Math1000 Added

Comment: that is not the limit of the characteristic function. “n” is not fixed along the product.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you elaborate? I don't see the problem

Comment: The characteristic function is $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-2\sin^2(t)/k),$ which is not what you wrote down.

Comment: The probability to stay in one place is increasing in the underlying process. Your computation of the CF does not reflect this.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen no that is not true. $X_{n+1}$ is not $X_n$ and then one more step. It is an entirely different random walk with a different underlying movement function. For every $X_n$, the movement function is defined differently and does not change with steps

Comment: @Ian It is increasing, but it doesn't go to $1$ (since number of steps is also increasing) and then the final CF isn't $\equiv 1$

Comment: @Anvit Ok, misread the problem. Then those variables converge in distribution to the cf you calculated. What do you want? A closed form for the density?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen A closed form would be good but I just want some intuition on how the random variable would look like. Obviously, it would take value in $2\mathbb Z$ but can we say anything more?

Comment: Your computation is wrong, the $Z_n$ are obviously not iid and there's no closed form for the characteristic function.

Comment: @GabrielRomon For a fixed $n$, $X_n=Z_n+Z_n+\cdots+Z_n \,\,n$ times. I am not using the same index everywhere by mistake.

Comment: @Anvit Are you sure this is the right interpretation of the problem ? Sound more like $X_n=Z_1+\ldots+Z_n$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes, I am sure of that. That is what I explained in a comment addressed to spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: You can see that all its moments exist, compute them, see that it decays somewhat slower than a gaussian, etc.

Comment: @Anvit your clarified problem is ill-defined. You have only given the distribution of each $X_n$ but not the joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Think about it, each $X_n$ could live in a different probability space making the pointwise limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$ a meaningless expression. What you are calculating is the *weak* limit of the $X_n$, which is describing the limit of the distributions (or equivalently, limit of characteristic functions). Just pointing it out - you will confuse less people and get better responses if you use the right terminology in the future...

Comment: @pre-kidney, I intended it to be Limit of distributions only

Comment: well, that is not what the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$ means. You should edit your question to use a correct notation, like $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal L(X_n)$ where $\mathcal L(X_n)$ denotes the law (i.e. distribution) of the random variables $X_n$.